# How to properly put asterisk around a term?

Tags: creative-writing, style, grammar, titles

How do I properly put asterisk around this title? Do I put it at the end of the title of after the term, KonMari Method?

Which one is correct?

**How the KonMari Method Changed My Daily Routine***

or

**How the KonMari Method* Changed My Daily Routine**

At the end of the project, I put:

*Source: The Life-Changing Magic of Tidying Up: The Japanese Art of Decluttering and Organizing by Marie Kondo

Please help,
thank you!!! =)

-L

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the asterisk belongs in the title at all, to be honest with you. It's perfectly fine to have an unknown word or phrase in your project title, as there's the implicit understanding that you'll explain what the word/phrase means within the project itself.

So just write the title normally without the asterisk--

> **How the KonMari Method Changed My Daily Routine**

--and then make sure that, somewhere within your project, you explain what the KonMari method is and where it comes from.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I used your advice in my project! =)))